# Android : How to First Ask for 2 Permissions before onCreate?

Tags: android, permissions

**I'm having a problem with permissions ..
how can i update onCreate or something , after the user allows my app for the permissions request?**

**for example :**

```
     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_permissions);

        // checking if it's not allowed yet

        if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
        }


       // now here how can i do something or start New Activity after he allows all permissions?



}
```

**if i do :**

```
else {

}
```

**is not gonna work for me unless i restart my app**

Comment: You won't get the result from `requestPermissions()` before `onCreate()` finishes. Just do whatever you need to in `onRequestPermissionsResult()`, after you've determined if the permission is granted.

Comment: any example for what you mean ?

Comment: See your comment `// now here how can i do something or start New Activity ...`? Don't do the "something or start New Activity" there. Do it in `onRequestPermissionsResult()` instead. Look at [the example on the developer page](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html#handle-response). You would do it where the `// permission was granted, yay! ...` comment is.

Comment: thanks a lot Mike! have a nice day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use libs https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher

Example:

```
 @RuntimePermissions
 public class AppTopView1Activity extends AppCompatActivity{
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_top_view_1);
    AppTopView1ActivityPermissionsDispatcher.checkPermissionWithCheck(this);
  }
 }

@NeedsPermission({Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA})
void checkPermission(){
    // allow Permission : Code here
}

@OnPermissionDenied({Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.CAMERA})
void showDeniedForCamera() {
    // don't allow Permission : Code here
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    AppTopView1ActivityPermissionsDispatcher.onRequestPermissionsResult(this, requestCode, grantResults);
}
```